# React: Parent and Memo Child – Preserving State in the Parent

Tags: reactjs, react.memo

I need to create a form with multiple subforms. Updating a property should not update the subforms. I'm using React.memo to achieve this.

However, the values on the form disappear whenever a property in the subform is changed.

For example, if I enter 'test' in the first field and then 'test' in the second field, the value in the first field disappears.

I believe my current approach is not correct. How can I address this issue?

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const ChildA = ({onChange, initForm}) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({...initForm})
  const update = e => {
    let newForm = {...form, name: e.target.value}
    setForm(newForm)
    onChange('childA', newForm)
  }

  return <>
    <input value={form.name} onChange={e => update(e)} />
    (Updated at : {new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { timeStyle: "medium" })})
  </>
}
const MemoChildA = React.memo(ChildA, () => true)

const ChildB = ({onChange, initForm}) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({...initForm})
  const update = e => {
    let newForm = {...form, name: e.target.value}
    setForm(newForm)
    onChange('childB', newForm)
  }

  return <>
    <input value={form.name} onChange={e => update(e)} />
    (Updated at : {new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { timeStyle: "medium" })})
  </>
}
const MemoChildB = React.memo(ChildB, () => true)

function Parent() {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({name:'', childA:{name: null}, childB:{name: null}})

  const change = (key, value) => {
    setForm({...form, [key]: value})
  }

  return <>
    <div>
      Parent Name : <input value={form.name} onChange={e => setForm({...form, name: e.target.value})} />
      (Updated at : {new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { timeStyle: "medium" })})
    </div>
    <div>
      ChildA Name : <MemoChildA onChange={change} form={{...form.childA}}/>
    </div>
    <div>
      ChildB Name : <MemoChildB onChange={change} form={{...form.childB}}/>
    </div>
  </>
}

export default Parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `React.memo()` is an *optimization* - you should not rely on it and indeed the [documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) explicitly says:

> If your code doesn’t work without it, find the underlying problem and
> fix it first

If you remove the `useMemo`, the problem with child updates erasing the parent state disappear, so that's step 1.

You've already got each child looking after its own `state`, but this is then duplicated in the parent in this structure:

```
{
    name: "",
    childA: { name: null },
    childB: { name: null }
  }
```

[Duplication of state is a major cause of bugs](https://react.dev/learn/choosing-the-state-structure) and needs to be eliminated, even before we consider any problem with excessive re-rendering.

There's also the [anti-pattern](https://react.dev/learn/choosing-the-state-structure) of "mirroring `props` in `state`" here:

```
const ChildA = ({ onChange, initForm }) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({ ...initForm });
  ...
```

The children are written as if `initForm` will only ever be their *initial* value - but `initForm` will actually be changing all the time.

If we declare the parent as the owner (or ["single source of truth"](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#a-single-source-of-truth-for-each-state)) of all form state (and this will make getting accurate data out of it much easier later) we get much less code and (IMO) it's far easier to follow:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ChildA = ({ onChange, myForm }) => {
  const update = (e) => {
    let newForm = { ...myForm, name: e.target.value };
    onChange("childA", newForm);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input value={myForm?.name} onChange={(e) => update(e)} />
      (Updated at : {new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { timeStyle: "medium" })}
      )
    </>
  );
};

const ChildB = ({ onChange, myForm }) => {
  const update = (e) => {
    let newForm = { ...myForm, name: e.target.value };
    onChange("childB", newForm);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input value={myForm?.name} onChange={(e) => update(e)} />
      (Updated at : {new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { timeStyle: "medium" })}
      )
    </>
  );
};

function Parent() {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: "",
    childA: { name: null },
    childB: { name: null }
  });

  const change = (key, value) => {
    setForm({ ...form, [key]: value });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        Parent Name :{" "}
        <input
          value={form.name}
          onChange={(e) => setForm({ ...form, name: e.target.value })}
        />
        (Updated at :{" "}
        {new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], { timeStyle: "medium" })})
      </div>
      <div>
        ChildA Name : <ChildA onChange={change} form={form.childA} />
      </div>
      <div>
        ChildB Name : <ChildB onChange={change} form={form.childB} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Parent;
```

You'll note that each sub-form **is** re-rendering on each change. Now that it's [working properly](https://codesandbox.io/s/codepen-with-react-forked-8n3v7q?file=/src/components/App.js), you could *consider* re-adding `React.memo` with a suitable [`arePropsEqual`](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo) test. But make sure you're not [over-estimating the cost of a re-render](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/why-react-re-renders/). Is it worth it, really?